# PHP: Creating a unique identifier for clients (independent of time, cookies and IP number)

Tags: php, http

I am thinking of a method for banning users 
* Creating a hash value for multiple variables coming from the user, (like browser and version and something else) and adding them to a table which stores a list of banned users or such values. I've found a list of http vriables here http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
but I think you probably have experience in this one. I am planning to use it to ban people from the website when necessary and renewing IP number and removing the cookies should not help the person to gain access.

What variables can I use to generate an identifier for the client?

Answer (score 2):

It's just for information, because what I'm going to talk is specific to platform and configuration, but here are some techniques to uniquely identify a user:

- [Get Client CPU ID with Javascript](http://codingresource.blogspot.fr/2010/01/get-client-cpu-id-with-javascript.html) (in IE, with ActiveX and poor security configuration)
- [Flash Interface MachineToken](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashaccess/2.0/javadocs/com/adobe/flashaccess/sdk/cert/MachineToken.html) (Adobe Flash Individualization Service)

Answer (score 1):

By combining *enough* data, you can reduce the false positives. Much more good information here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/is-browser-fingerprinting-a-viable-technique-for-identifying-anonymous-users

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you'll never be able to create a truly unique identifier, you'll just some circumstantial data pointing out who *may* be a culprit. There is no good way to do this, as most unique data is data given by the client.

Not all hope is lost though, by combining lots of different data like *geoip*, *sessions*, *user agent* and *access time* you may get enough data identify a **possible** ban breaker, but you'll never have enough data to truly identify a user; especially if that user knows how to clear cookies and alter their user agent.